# Exporting lists of channels and associated fields?

Tags: channel, fields, export

Is there a simple way of exporting all the channels and associated fields?

Rather than copying everything out of the channel field groups manually, I'm looking for a simple way (even via a plugin) to export the list of channels and associated fields.

While all the fields are usually planned out in advance, the final product is a little different and I want something that could be easy to print out - for a variety of reasons, including double-checking the work and making a usage guide for end users.

Comment: This add-on will display all of the fields in a slightly different format; not sure if it's enough of an improvement over copy/pasting manually from the control panel's normal way of showing custom fields though:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export / import field groups with [Field Editor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-editor), although it's in json format you should be able to reformat the text to suit your purposes.

Comment: Ah. json will work just fine. I'll probably just import to excel, and it'll format nicely enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that I know of that will summarise your Channels and Field Groups like that but I think [Field Editor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-editor) will probably be the closest to what you need.

It will allow you to save your field groups for import/export along with providing a useful on-screen summary if you wanted a visual reference.